# I am reading JSON data from kafka and parsing the data using spark. But I end up with JSON parser issue

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am reading JSON data from kafka and parsing the data  using spark. But I end up  with JSON parser issue. Code shown below:

```
val Array(zkQuorum, groupId, topics, numThreads) = args
    val conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("KafkaAggregation")
   // create sparkContext                 
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    
   // streaming context 
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

    //    ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://localhost:8020/usr/tmp/data")
    
    val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, groupId, topicMap).map((_._2))
    
    val lineJson = lines.map(JSON.parseFull(_))
                  .map(_.get.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]])
```

Error details:
error: not found: value JSON
[INFO]     val lineJson = lines.map(JSON.parseFull(_))

Which maven dependency should use I to sort out the error?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
```

ANd adding Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-parser-combinators</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-parser-combinators/2.11.0-M4

Comment: I have added the above maven dependency but  the issue has not been sorted out.

Comment: Did you run a mvn or sbt build? Could you paste here the entire error message?

Comment: I am using maven build. its acutally a compilation error.